# Why NSTimer doesn't stop with invalidate?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, nstimer

I make a Cocoa application.I create a NSTimer,it can work,but can't stop with invalidate.The following is my code.Anyone else can help me?

```
@implementation Document
{
  NSTimeInterval elapsedTime;
  NSTimer *timer;
}

- (IBAction)start:(id)sender
{
   elapsedTime = 0.002f;
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
     if(timer == nil)
   {
    NSLog(@"Starting");
    captureFrame = [[CaptureFrame alloc] init];//captureFrame is another object
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:elapsedTime target:captureFrame selector:@selector(sendSingleImageImage) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    NSThread *thread = [NSThread currentThread];
    NSLog(@"Current thread is%@",thread);// I want to see the thread.
   }
  else
   {
    NSLog(@"Exist!");
    [timer invalidate];
    timer = nil;
   } 
  });
  [_stopButton setEnabled:YES];
  [_startButton setEnabled:NO];
}
- (IBAction)stop:(id)sender
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       [timer invalidate];
       timer = nil;
       NSThread *sthread = [NSThread currentThread];
       NSLog(@"S thread is %@",sthread);// I want to see the thread
    });
   [_startcastButton setEnabled:YES];
   [_stopButton setEnabled:NO];
   NSLog(@"Stopping");
}
```

I tried use the following method,but didn't work.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void)block)
```

I also tried to find whether two actions in the same thread,and the result is yes.

So please tell me how to stop the NSTimer.
Any help is appreciated,thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Why do you work with threads!? Action methods are called on the main thread (because they are a result of user interaction.) Every thread has its own runloop so using timers over threads does not make sense. Is `-stop:` executed from different threads? (BTW: `-setEnabled:` should be executed on the main thread, too.)

Comment: I agree with @AminNegm-Awad about threads.  The only thing your dispatches are doing is making "S thread is" print **after** "Stopping" instead of before it.  I tried your code (except that I moved your selector into the same class) and it looked OK.  Why do you think `invalidate` isn't stopping your timer?

Comment: Actually when I invoke the `-stop:`,the `[timer isValid]` become `NO`,but the method which `timer` called on is also periodically working.When `[timer invalidate]` and the `[timer isValid]` become `NO`,`timer` should stop call on the method,isn't it?

Comment: Yes, it should and it does in my sample.  Here's something to try: Change your selector to `@selector(sendSingleImageImage:)` and its signature to `- (void)sendSingleImageImage:(NSTimer *)timer`.  Log the value of `timer` when you first create it.  Put a breakpoint after `[timer invalidate]`.  When the app hits your breakpoint, put another breakpoint inside `sendSingleImageImage:`.  Continue.  When it hits the second one, compare the value of the `timer` parameter (its address) to the timer you created.

Comment: Maybe there can be a race condition because you do the dispatch: Since it is not guaranteed when to be executed, one might press the start button while the timer is on to stop. However, I do not think that this is your problem. Likely you have more than one timer running. I would do @PhillipMills suggestion and additionally throw away the whole dispatch things, because they are meaningless in your code.

Comment: Now I know the point.In fact, removing the `timer` did stop calling the method.When I remove the`timer`,the method also will run for a period of time.Finally it will stop.`@Amin Negm-Awad` ,`@Phillip Mills`